# How to handle a `datetime` value so to change it from `2012-04-27 00:00:00` to `27 april 2012`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, date

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 and I would like to display a data as-like `<day_number> <month_name> <year_number>`. That is, I have a `datetime` database table column and I would like to change its contained values, for example, from `2012-04-27 00:00:00` to `27 april 2012`.

How can I make that?

Comment: Err, why don't you just store it as a `date` instead of a `datetime`?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - It is because I would like to be as precise as possible. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way is use rails localization.

model

```
I18n.l(datetime, :format => :short)
```

controller

```
I18n.l(datetime, :format => :long)
```

view

```
<%= l(datetime), :format => :custom %>
```

config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  time:
    formats:
      long: "%A %B %d %Y | %I:%M %p GMT"
      short: "%d %B %Y, %H:%M GMT"
      custom: "your custom format"
  date:
    formats:
      short: "%d %B %Y"
      long: "%A %B %d %Y"
      custom: "your custom format"
```

In your case the format should be "%d %A %Y".

The benefit is if you want to change format you can do it in one place for all datetimes which you are using.

Comment: Technically, how are "named" all those `%A %B %d %Y ...` and where I can find some documentation about so to choose the best format I need?

Comment: try this http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2255 or http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime or try google with keywords [ strftime ruby ] :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method

```
str_name.strftime("%d %A %Y")
```